# Is former sso login session is invalidated when i login in another browser by WSO2 Identity Server?

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I would like to know whether WSO2 Identity Server supports session concurrency management? So i want configure the pre-defined maximum number of open concurrent session for each service provider. When this number was exceeded then either oldest of former session logout or no any login session has been setup.

Exist any possible ways or ideas for session authentication strategy that manage session concurrency in WSO2 Identity Server?

Cab be solved this problem with enabling authentication session persistence?

appreciate for your cooperation

Answer (score 0):

There is No specific way we can track the session to support concurrent session management in such way.

AFAIK in session persistence it only persists some session but no information related to its service provider , therefore we can not limit number of concurrent sessions to be handle by a specific service provider.

To you can get some idea on this by following this guide [1]

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS510/Enabling+Authentication+Session+Persistence